# Global function works in a code but not in the other (not defined)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made the global function below:

```
global.findPlayer = function findPlayer(name) {
    let players = mp.players.toArray();
    for(let p in players) {
        if(players[p].name == name) {
            return players[p];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Basically, it checks if a player is online in the server and if he is it returns true.
The problem is the following: I have two commands in the same file (a different file from where the global is stored) and they both call the function. One of them works, but the other says it isn't defined.

The code below works. It checks if a player is online, and if he is the player who typed the command gets teleported to his target.

```
mp.events.addCommand("isplayeronline", (player, targetPlayer) => {
    if (findPlayer(targetPlayer)) player.position = targetPlayer.position;
    else player.outputChatBox("Nope")
});
```

The code below doesn't work. It checks thru many errors and throws them if they're verified., including if a player is offline. If the player is online and if (supposedly) there are no errors, it sends "Banana" to the player.

```
mp.events.addCommand('admin', (player, targetPlayer, targetAdminLevel) => {
        player.outputChatBox("Banana")
    try {
        if (player.adminLevel < 8)  throw "Este comando só está disponível para administradores de nível superior a 8.";
        if (!targetPlayer) throw "Uso: /admin <ID/NOME> <NÍVEL DE ADMINISTRADOR>.";
        if (player.adminLevel <= targetAdminLevel) throw "Não podes promover alguém a um nível superior ao teu.";
        if (!findPlayer(targetPlayer)) throw "Esse jogador não existe ou não está online."

    }
    catch(err) {
        player.outputChatBox(`!{${corErro}}${err}`)
    }
    finally {
        console.log("Finally")
    }
});
```

I get the error: `ReferenceError: findPlayer is not defined`

Also, I get the message "Banana" everytime, despite of any errors I make. Where should I put the message function so it only works if there are no errors?

Comment: I'm so confused. The second argument for `isplayeronline` is a player object, right? That object is passed into findPlayer, therefore `name` is a player object? `for(let p in players) {...}` sets `p` to player objects so how does `players[p]` return *anything* much less an object with a `name` property equivalent to the player object that was passed into findPlayer?

Comment: The second argument is a string. It then goes check if that string exists

Comment: the second argument, `targetPlayer`, is a string that has a `position` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findPlayer is a property of global not a variable, so use it like `global.findPlayer()`

Comment: Thanks. I swear I had tried that already and it didn't work. Probably made a typo. Appreciated.